# Time machine cannot see a external drive

Tags: mac, time-machine, time

I just replaced my time machine drive with a larger unit. Now it cannot see the external thunderbolt drive  I use for all my photo editing that I need to backup. On time machine options it is missing. Yet shows up fine in finder and is working great in lightroom etc.can anyone help?

Comment: Double check the TM options/exclusions.  I suspect that your thunderbolt drive has been excluded automatically - if so, remove from exclusions.

Comment: Check the disk format. TM won't backup NTFS, not sure about FAT or if the underlying scheme must be GUID not MBR, but it's worth a look.